# Update file and commit with gitlab

Tags: api, gitlab, commit

I want to change the context of file and commit by using gitlab api. I looked the api documentation and couldn't find a way to do it. 
The documentation link is here;
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/

Is it possible to do change the file and commit it?  Do you have any example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official documentation for updating a file via the api: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#update-existing-file-in-repository

Example:

```
curl --request PUT --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fproject%2Erb?branch=master&author_email=author%40example.com&author_name=Firstname%20Lastname&content=some%20other%20content&commit_message=update%20file'
```

Related question: [Updating and committing file by using gitlab api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45837806/updating-and-committing-file-by-using-gitlab-api/47941653#47941653)

Answer (score -3):

You should use git for this use case, not the API which is not designed for this!