# Updating and committing file by using gitlab api

Tags: git, gitlab, commit, git-commit, gitlab-api

I want to update file content and commit it. To be able to achieve it, I looked the api of gitlab from the url;
http://mygitlabadress/help/api/README.md

It says Updating existing file is done as;
http://mygitlabadress/help/api/repository_files.md#update-existing-file-in-repository

I follow the instructions and write;
http://mygitlabadress/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/files/file1%2Ffile2%2Ftest?ref=master&author_name=name%20surname&content=some%20other%20content&commit_message=update%20file&private_token=:PRIVATE_TOKEN

This returns as;
{"file_name":"test","file_path":"file1/file2/test","size":5,"encoding":"base64","content":"ZmRhcwo=","ref":"master","blob_id":"e1afa79f4...","commit_id":"5d61796...","last_commit_id":"5d617962a23c07345e68..."}

But when I check commits on master branch. The commit is not done. I don't understand why this is happening. The above request doesn't return an error. On the contrary, it returns as commit is done.

What am I missing? How can I update the file and commit it??

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are making a GET request instead of a PUT.

Are you using curl ? You should use the example `curl` request given in the doc :

> curl --request PUT --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fproject%2Erb?branch=master&author_email=author%40example.com&author_name=Firstname%20Lastname&content=some%20other%20content&commit_message=update%20file'